# Multiple persist in Symfony 3 Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony3.x

I have a database with 3 tables, Equipment, transaction and transactionReceive. In the future there will be multiple transactionXYZ, one for each type of transaction. I used a joined inheritance to link transactionReceive with transaction. I also use a Many to one association between Equipment and transaction, since a piece of equipment can have multiple transactions.

I am currently working on adding a piece of equipment. This is a two step process. It should:
1: Create the piece of equipment
2: Create the transaction/transactionReceive

My issue is that when I try to set the equipmentId to persist the transaction, it throws an exception saying it is null.

My code is as follow:

```
$em->persist($equipmentData);
$em->flush();

$trans = new TransactionReceive();
$trans->setEquipmentId($equipmentData->getId()); 
//Here I set all transactions info 

$em->persist($trans);
$em->flush();
```

Thanks

EDIT:
Apparently my issue would be related to the insert with the ManyToOne association. I noticed it because I get the same error even if I hardcode a value for the equipmentId in the transaction.

EDIT 2:
Transaction entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Transaction
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="transaction")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TransactionRepository")
 *
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="transactionType", type="string")
 * ORM\@DiscriminatorMap({
 *  "receive" = "TransactionReceive", 
 *  "changeout" = "TransactionChangeoutWheelset",
 * })
 */
class Transaction
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Equipment")
 * @ORM\Column(name="equipmentId", type="integer")
 */
private $equipmentId;

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getequipmentId()
{
    return $this->equipmentId;
}
/**
 * @param int $equipmentId
 *
 * @return self
 */
public function setEquipmentId($equipmentId)
{
    $this->equipmentId= $equipmentId;
    return $this;
}
// Other attributes, getters and setters
```

TransactionReceive entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Transaction;
/**
 * TransactionReceive
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="transaction_receive")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TransactionReceiveRepository")
 */
class TransactionReceive extends Transaction
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="gsThickness", type="integer")
     */
    private $gsThickness;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Set gsThickness
     *
     * @param integer $gsThickness
     *
     * @return TransactionReceive
     */
    public function setGsThickness($gsThickness)
    {
        $this->gsThickness = $gsThickness;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get gsThickness
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getGsThickness()
    {
        return $this->gsThickness;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the exact exception text?

Comment: "An exception occurred while executing `INSERT INTO transaction (date, employeeID, location, equipmentId, transactionType) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)` with params ["2018-06-29 10:33:55", 1, "Location", null, "transactionReceive"];

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column `equipmentId` cannot be null

Comment: can you show the `TransactionReceive` entity?

Comment: Code added in Edit 2

Comment: Ah, I was asking to see what your annotations were for the `equipmentId` preprety in `tansactionRecieve` xD Any change you can add that?

Comment: This is the code, but it is in Transaction. Should it be in TransactionReceive?   
 /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Equipment")
     * @ORM\Column(name="equipmentId", type="integer")
     */
    private $equipmentId;

Comment: It can be in both. if you log `$equipmentData->getId()` before `$trans->setEquipmentId($equipmentData->getId());`, is it a number, or already null?

Comment: even if i do $tran->setEquipmentId(2); it gives the same error. (And yes 2 is a valid ID in my DB for now)

Comment: can you show the function `setEquipmentId` in your entity?

Comment: Added in Edit 2 text, it is under the Transaction Entity

Comment: hum... is it possible that equipementId is set back to null between the set and the flush?

Comment: It is not, i set it, then i persist, then flush. I was wondering if this could be an obscure Symfony settings because of the ManyToOne association. Is the id supposed to be automatically filled?

Comment: Also, if equipment data is the only persist, it works (as in doesn`t break and the data gets in the equipment table). But I need the transaction to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `equipementId` proprety is a foreign key, you need to set it to an object equipement, not only it's Id.

Replacing the line `$trans->setEquipmentId($equipmentData->getId());` by

```
$trans->setEquipmentId($equipmentData);
```

should do the trick for you.